# Sprites reshape unexpectedly

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

Using Unity 4.6.0 .
I've imported some sprites to my project . I attached an image of one of these sprites (It's only a prefab with `SpriteRenderer` Component attached to it)

[image]

But sometimes Unity reshapes the sprite automatically

[image]

And if I change some settings of these sprites like Max Size or Format, then the sprites will be rendered correctly but after a while it will be reshaped again! I don't have any idea about this problem.

Comment: Do you receive any console messages when this happens?

Comment: When I stop the game, sometimes a console message appears:  !CompareApproximately (det, 1.0F, .005f)  UnityEditor.SceneView:Awake()  UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility:LoadSerializedFileAndForget(String)  UnityEditor.EditorApplicationLayout:SetStopmodeLayout()

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you parent your sprite to an object that has a scale other than (1, 1, 1). If any object higher up in the hierarchy is scaled it will affect all children including your sprite.

You can either counter the scaling or use [Transform.SetParent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) to do it for you.